# Regex to fetch Verses and Chorus from song lyrics

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I want to use `preg_match_all` to create an array with all the Verses and Chorus from the Lyrics below.  What regex should I use?

```
[V1]
 Fugi, fugi de păcate, nu te-apropia, 
 Duce la pierzare calea lumii rea. 
 Fii treaz şi te roagă, fii încrezător, 
 Cu Isus în luptă eşti biruitor!
[C] 
 Vino-n rugăciune, 
 spune-I starea ta, 
 In Isus te-ncrede,
 El te va-ajuta.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
preg_match_all('#\[([VC]\d?)\]([^\[]*)#s', $s, $matches);
```

Match only verses from 0 to 9, but can be easily updated with `*` modifier.

Comment: it should be ideal that one array has the V1,V2,C tags and one array should have just the lyrics. Is this possible?

Comment: @Filip I've add brackets to my answers, is it okay?

Answer (score -1):

Go get any Verses: [`\[V\[0-9\]\]\[^\[\]+`](http://regexr.com/39csa). For Chorus [`\[C\]\[^\[\]+`](http://regexr.com/39cs7)

To omit [Vx] and [C] use [`Named Capturing Groups`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html) : `\[V\[0-9\]\](?P=<music>\[^\[\]+)` and `\[C\](?P=<music>\[^\[\]+)`

Comment: it is possible that the [Vx] and [C] should be ommited from the output? I want just the text.